# imageView not display an image from external storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so am trying to make an app and part of the app i have to upload a picture from the phone and display it in imageview and keep the picture on it , i searched and i found a way in a video. the problem is  the imageview didnt display the picture . i try many things like change in the code or even change in the xml  file like make the imageview wrap content and remove the scaleType but the same no thing change , i understand like 80% from the code but in the last method  I get lost so if anyone can help me i will be grateful

java code

```
public class AddCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 0 ;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 0 ;
ImageView imageView ;
Button btn ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_category);
  imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageAddCategory) ;
  btn = findViewById(R.id.add_po);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
              != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
              requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSION_REQUEST);

              }
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
              Intent ii = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
              startActivityForResult(ii,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
          }

      }
  });
}




@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this," PERMISSION GRANTED" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this," PERMISSION NOT GRANTED" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                assert data != null;
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED};
                assert selectedImage != null;
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn
                        , null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();


            }

    }
}
}
```